# Using Like with a Wildcard Parameter

Tags: sql-server

I have a parameter:

```
where udf.[UDFText13] Like '%' + @SearchWindow + '%'
```

Query runs just fine but if I enter BAT in the prompt, I don't see rows where `'BATT'` is in the `UDFText13` field.

I've spent some time trying to figure out if `CONTAINS()` would work better but figure out the correct syntax.

Comment: Could there be whitespace in your input field? Try `'%' + TRIM(@SearchWindow) + '%'`

Comment: Have you tried running the query after replacing all the parameters? Such as in your case: "where udf.[UDFText13] Like '%BAT%'

Comment: TRIM isn't a recognized function in sql server so I tried RTRIM but still didn't see all of the rows that I know I should see. Paurian I don't understand what your comment means.

Comment: Can you post a script that reproduces the problem?   There is nothing wrong with the code you have posted.

Comment: could you do a LEN(@SearchWindow) to see if there's any data in there that shouldn't be?

Comment: Here are the records I should be seeing when using LIKE:

Comment: TASK_CODE
25BAT1-1725
25BAT3-1725
25BAT2-1725
26BATT-1726
26BATT-BSB-1726
26BATT-ASA-1726

Comment: LisaRose Paurian is suggesting you run your query unparameterized to see if it works then, so instead of "where udf.[UDFText13] Like '%' + @SearchWindow + '%'" you do "where udf.[UDFText13] Like '%BAT%' and see what happens. If it works as expected in the 2nd case, you likely have an issue with your parameter.